# Rendering darkspot

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render a glass bottle filled with mushrooms but a darkspot keeps appearing. I also tried to place a light directly above it but it keeps happening. Is there anything i can do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe it's just reflecting the environment, what does it give if you use an HDRI image, or a brighter Background color?

Comment: I have added a background colour. i dont know what an HDRI image is however. The wierd thing is sometimes the darkspot is white instead of black

Comment: I have just redone the shape and that fixed it. I still dont know what the issue was tho. But thanks for holding my hand throught this moonboots :)